# How to set color in graphics in C#

Tags: java, c#

How to set color in graphics in c#?
`SetColor` method not working.

How do I convert the following Java code to C#?

```
private Graphics g1;

g1.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(h, 0.8f, b)); 
Color col = Color.getHSBColor(h, 0.8f, b);
int red = col.getRed();
int green = col.getGreen();
int blue = col.getBlue();
```

Comment: Those function names on `Color` and `Graphics` look like they are from a java class but your question is tagged C#, which language is it?

Comment: It's c# code are you sure?

Comment: I think you are using `java.awt.Graphics` from j++ ;).

Comment: He may be asking about converting that Java code in to equivalent C# code.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is a java code.

Comment: And yes i'm trying to convert into c# code.

Comment: My sincere apology. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing model in C# is slightly different.  Instead of setting resources, like color, on a graphic object, you create resources, such as `Pen`, or `Brush` that have properties on them, like `Color`.  You then use those objects to draw on an image.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(someBitMap); //create a graphics object for an existing BitMap
Color c = new Color(255,0,0); //a "red" color
Pen p = new Pen(c); //create a Pen using the Red color from earlier
p.Width = 5; //Pen is 5 pixels wide

g.DrawLine(p, 0,0,100,100); //draw a diagonal line

//Get rbg values.
int r = c.R;
int g = c.G;
int b = c.B;

//It is VERY important to call `.Dispose()` on GDI objects.  They contain unmanaged system resources that can, and will, leak if you don't.
g.Dispose()
p.Dispose()
```

It looks like you might be trying to convert a color from the HSB color-space to RGB.  Unfortunately, that isn't natively supported in .NET.  The following blog post has some code that can do that for you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2006/04/12/converting-from-hsb-to-rgb-in-net/

Comment: Thank you very much Bradley.